# How to query a column created by aggregate function in hive?

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive, aggregate-functions

In hive, I want to select the records with `users>=40`. My table column consist of field `userid`. So i used

`select title,sum(rating),count(userid) from table_name where count(userid)>=40 
group by title order by rating desc`

But it showed error like you can't use count in where clause. Also i have tried using alias like

`select title,sum(rating) as ratings,count(userid) as users where users>=40 group by title order by ratings desc`

Here also i struck up with error showing users is not a column name in table.
I need to get title with maximum ratings having minimum 40 users

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want the *having* clause:

```
select title, sum(rating), count(userid) 
rom table_name
group by title
having count(userid) >= 40 
order by sum(rating) desc;
```

In Hive, you may need to use a column alias, though:

```
select title, sum(rating) as rating, count(userid) as cnt
rom table_name
group by title
having cnt >= 40 
order by rating desc;
```

Comment: Thanks, let me try that and vote your answer. My VMPlayer strucks. Soon i will update the result.